# can't execute external command in cgi

Tags: c, perl, cgi

I have this line code in my file `.pl`

```
system("./read_image http://echopaw.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/animals-41.jpg");
```

`read_image` is a C executable file, it works well in command line, but when I run my `.pl` file in web server, this line didn't work, its function is to write some data into a file, so I can see if it works

I also tried `` , but it still didn't work

anyone gets some ideas?

Comment: is the executable file in the correct directory? Using absolute path may be good.

Comment: In addition, use a list of arguments to `system`, and [check the return value](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#system-LIST): `system '/absolute/path/read_image', 'http://..../animals-42.jpg'`.

Comment: Nice moniker, but how can you be addressed (eg in comments) if someone tries to respond?  I am not sure how your moniker can be reproduced - @[?]

Comment: @ryyker, I got it. Interesting question, though! I cut'n'pasted the symbols 赵子龙 from his profile. Not sure whether it works. The `tab` does not work at last. But the OP is always notified.

Comment: @PerlDog - 赵子龙, Cool, did not know that it would be that easy.  Thanks.

Comment: @MikeCAT   i tried this `system("/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/read_image","http://www.allkpop.com/upload/2015/07/content/Shin-Se-Kyung_1437525895_shin2.jpg"); `  but it still did't work, when i make command like `cat test.txt`  il works well, so i must do something wrong there

Comment: @SinanÜnür   return value is 256

Comment: @赵子龙 That's "good" news. According to the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) this means your `read_image` _was_ actually executed, but returned itself `rc=1`. (If `system` couldn't execute your script, it would have returned `-1`). So there must be a problem with `read_image`, not with the call. We are narrowing it down :-)

Comment: Try `system("$FindBin::Bin/read_image http://... 2>/tmp/my-error.txt")` and look into the file /tmp/my-error.txt after failure. Perhaps it contains sth. useful. Do you have access to apache's error.log? Look there.

Comment: @PerlDog  i just saw in my error/log `[Mon Mar 21 08:53:57.868339 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 6769] [client ::1:65154] AH01215: sh: wget: command not found: /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/distance.pl
[Mon Mar 21 08:53:57.877116 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 6769] [client ::1:65154] AH01215: Empty input file: /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/distance.pl`    it seems like the command wget in my read_image didn't work, but when i execute in command line, it didn't have that error,  I'm sure i have wget, do you think it's the problem of permission or path of wget?

Comment: @PerlDog actually when i want to use a local image, i get almost the same error `AH01215: /usr/local/bin/djpeg: can't open /Users/zhaozilong/Documents/s8/ri/tp_media/img/winter.jpg: /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/distance.pl`   it's so weird, in command line, everything goes so well

Comment: @赵子龙 I updated my answer, see below.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because when your webserver runs your CGI then it does so from some wierd directory (`/var/www/htdocs` or `/` or whatever). Then your `read_image` is also expected to be in that directory because of the `./read_image`.
`./` means *current directory*, which is not necessarily the directory where your .cgi is located.
I'd suggest using the Perl module [FindBin](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html):

**your cgi:**

```
...
use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin;

...
system("$FindBin::Bin/read_image http://echopaw.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/animals-41.jpg");
```

`$FindBin::Bin` resolves to the path where your .cgi is located -- no matter where you call it from. It's a quite handy module and can also be used to pimp the @INC path to find your own modules:

```
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/../lib";
use MyModule;
```

This way `MyModule.pm` is expected to be in `$current_script_path/../lib`. Very convenient.

---

### Addendum

As the discussion evolves this is apparently not only a problem of whether apache can or cannot find the `read_image` command but also of whether `read_image` in turn can find the `wget` command which it tries to execute.

As @CDahn already noted in a comment apache runs CGI scripts and the like with a *limited environment* for security reasons. If you run `read_image` from your shell, then you have a fully working environment with, say, PATH including 15 different directories (like `/usr/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/share/bin:/usr/local/bin:...`, whatever). When apache runs your scripts, PATH may only contain 2 or 3 directories that are absolutely necessary, e.g. `/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin`. The same applies to other environment variables.

You can verify this with a little .cgi script that simply echoes the current environment, like

```
while (my ($key,$value) = each %ENV) {
    print "$key=$value\n";
}
```

(Taken from http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html)
Call this .cgi from your browser and you'll see the difference.

When your `read_image` cannot find the `wget` command then probably because `wget` is located in a PATH apache doesn't know of. Instead of teaching apache about the additional directory (bad idea), I would give the full path to `wget` command in your `read_image` program. From your terminal window run

```
$ which wget
/usr/bin/wget
```

and use that very path when calling `wget` from your `read_image`.

Comment: This could work, but remember that the CGI script is running as whatever user the web server is running as, and the environment is not a login shell environment. As such, the PATH variable may not be what one would expect. Using an absolute path here, or putting the binary in the CGI directory may be a more predictable option.

Comment: @CDahn To my understanding `FindBin` has nothing to do with the `PATH` variable. I does a `getcwd()` in all possible flavours to figure out the location of the script that `use`s it. Putting the binary in the CGI directory works only if _apache_ (for that matter) `cd`'s to the CGI directory prior to executing the .cgi. I don't want to argue, I just had _never_ bad experience with FindBin.

Comment: @PerlDog  i used this way to make the command, but it doesn't work, i tried to show the $FindBin, it's '/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/', i also tried this path absolute, but it didn't work, i run my .pl in command line, it works well, i really have no idea where is wrong

Comment: @PerlDog  and i have the permission -rwxrwxrwx   1 root        wheel     9296 Mar 20 15:03 read_image

Comment: @赵子龙 Slightly off-topic, but set the mode to 755 (-rwxr-xr-x) once you get it working. Else everybody can change/delete your file.

Comment: @PerlDog You're absolutely right. I must be getting old and starting to lose my mind.

Comment: @CDahn I hope you do! (getting old, not loosing your mind) :-) Cheers!

Comment: @PerlDog  hello genius, i used your solution, get where locate wget, use absolute path and it works,  thank you a lot!